# The differential of function that maps matrices

Tags: calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations

I have a question about the differential of function that maps matrices,for example if my function is $f(X)=X+X^2$,where $X$ is a $2\times2$ matrix with real numbers, what would be its differential?

I know how to find the differential matrix when its mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, but not sure how to work when its with matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea in differential calculus is the following: write $f(X+H)$ as $f(X)+\varphi(H)+R(H)$ where $\varphi$ is linear (and continuous) and $R(H)/\lVert H\rVert\underset{\lVert H\rVert\to0}\to0$. In this case, $\varphi$ is the differential of $f$ at $X$, that I denote by $D_Xf$.

In your case:
$$\begin{align*}
f(X+H)&=X+H+(X+H)^2\\
   &=X+H+X^2+XH+HX+H^2\\
   &=X+X^2+H+XH+HX+H^2\\
   &=f(X)+\varphi(H)+R(H)
\end{align*}$$
where $\varphi(H)=H+XH+HX$ is linear and $R(H)=H^2$ and we do have: $R(H)/\lVert H\rVert\underset{\lVert H\rVert\to0}\to0$ (show it). Hence,
$$D_X f(H)=H+XH+HX.$$